# AS2 - Accessing movieclip properties from inside another movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have 2 movieclips.  One is a fairy flying up the stage.  The other movieclip is a magic dust, which is originally designed to generate magic dust with onMouseMove event, based on the mouse's x & y.  I want to change the the magic dust movieclip so it will generate magic dust following the fairy's movement.

this.onMouseMove = function() {
 generator(this._xmouse,this._ymouse,5);
 generator(this._xmouse,this._ymouse,10);
};

1) What event do I use in the magic dust movieclip? onEnterFrame?
2) How do I access the fairy's x & y info?

Thanks.

Comment: The solution suggested by Zevan did get me the x & y of the fairy movieclip. But the x & y values do not change while the fairy is flying around the stage:-( So the fairy movieclip's x & y are not the values that the dust movieclip needs to track.  What should the dust movieclip track instead?

Comment: can you post a link to your fla file? I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

There's many options. You can update dust every frame with faerie coords from code, or give the dust reference to the faerie.

Answer (score 0):

Give the fairy an instance name "fairy" and instead of

```
this._xmouse/this._ymouse
```

use

```
_parent.fairy._x / _parent.fairy._y
```

Comment: It works, but the dust is not working as I image:-(  See the comment above.